# Which graphics card is XP using in my Macbook Pro?

Tags: windows-xp, macbook, graphics-card

The Macbook Pro has two graphics cards, one which is built in and another one that is more powerful.

I installed XP Pro using bootcamp.  Which graphics card is XP using, and how can I switch the graphics card that XP uses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To switch your graphical card, [go to](http://www.lancelhoff.com/switching-video-cards-macbook-pro/) Energy Preferences and select the other "profile" on the top. It's counter-intuitive, I know.

To see your graphical card on Windows, as people already pointed, you have two options: press [Win Key] + [R] and type either "dxdiag" or "devmgmt.msc" and look for the "Display".

I believe there's no way to switch card in Windows, tho. I've [read](http://forums.macrumors.com/showpost.php?p=7596830&postcount=2) it will always use the only most powerful one. Which makes some sense - why else would you run Windows on Bootcamp if not for playing games?

Answer (score 1):

Look in the [Device Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_Manager) in XP, under Display Adapters.  It'll show you which one it's using.  As for switching, I have no idea.  Not sure Boot Camp can do that.  I also don't think XP would support switching a graphics card while it was running.  You'd most likely have to reboot.

Answer (score 0):

`Start > Run > dxdiag > System and Display tab`

You should get a wealth of information on which graphics card XP is using.